# bootstrapping code in R doesn't work?

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

So I am ready to jump off a building because I cannot figure out this code for my LIFE. Everytime I run it, I get the standard error of 0 (bias=0 too) so obviously I'm doing something wrong because it's using the same sample when I want 1000 iterations.

I want the AIC of the model for all these samples. I've created a data frame and named it "d."

Here is my code:

```
bootaic<-function(d, idx){
d2<-d[idx,]
fit<-coxph(Surv(time,infection) ~ X48FL + X55FL, method="efron", data=d)
return(AIC(fit))
}

bootf<-boot(data=d,statistic=bootaic,R=1000)
```

WHAT IS WRONG. I appreciate any and all help, I am a novice to bootstrapping and I suck at coding.

Comment: You create `d2` and then you use `d` in the model call.

Comment: Hi! I thought I use my original dataset there...

Comment: Nonetheless, even with d2 it doesn't work..

Comment: I am following this link: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/boot.htm but alas. Not working

Comment: 1. does the regression look OK? `summary(fit)` 2. does `AIC(fit)` return a single number?

Comment: Yes. I got it to work! I have another problem if you would not mind hearing me out. How would I go about bootstrapping FACTORS? As in, I want factors to be extracted, and then want the AIC of the same model as the output? Well, the model wouldn't be the same because I wouldn't have X48FL...etc, I would have FAC1. But I can't just use the factors in the formula can I...

Comment: @lmo i hope this makes sense lol

Comment: @Didi Are you talking about altering the specification of your model within each bootstrap but removing some factor variables and rerunning it?

Comment: Yes. To me that seems a bit weird but yes..altering it with each bootstrap but I still wanna end up with 5 factors. Why would this be preferred over extracting factors from the original model, and then doing a bootstrap on those?

Comment: @Imo I forget to do the @ thingy